# "Could not find "store" in the context of" error during the creating of a reusable react-redux package

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using [croods](https://croods-docz.netlify.com/) (A package that abstracts redux actions and reducers) on a package that I'm developing.
When I put croods as peerDependencies, the library works on his example, but I can't test it without croods installed (I must install to mock it).

If I install croods as devDependency or a normal dependency on the library, the tests become ok, but on the example (that has croods installed) I keep getting the `Could not find "store" in the context of (...)`.

These attempts related to dependencies/bundle are not promising. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `react`, `redux`, `react-redux` versions all match up. I've seen this error when mixing (major) versions of `react-redux` in dependencies.

Comment: I cant keep these as peerDependencies and it work on the example, but how do I test without putting these dependencies on dev/depencies of my project?

Comment: I can****
And that is other point that I don't understand, when I put it croods as devDependency of the library I am creating, the example of my library doesn't work. But this should work, because devDependencies of the library should to be irrelevant to the project that uses the library